# Listen For Incoming Value Using Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase to manage the server for my game. The game needs input from users on either end.

The app allows players to play a small game, where either player picks a random card and then the server compares the two. However, when one player picks a card before the other, I need the app to wait until the value is received. So, I need the app to 'wait' until a value is entered, then the app will continue. That way I can compare either value (the value from player 1 and the value from player 2)

This is how I'm attempting it right now:

```
@IBAction func aceOfClubs(_ sender: Any) {
    cardSelected(imageString: "aceOfClubs", cardValue: aceOfClubsValue)
}
```

When a player presses a button it runs this function:

```
private func cardSelected(imageString: String, cardValue: Int) {
    print("card selected")

    self.currentPlayerChosenCard.image = UIImage(named: imageString)

    setCardValueForPlayer(player: 1, cardValue: cardValue)
    var playerOneCardValue = checkCardValue(player: 2)

    while playerOneCardValue == 0 {
        print("while loop performed")
        playerOneCardValue = checkCardValue(player: 2)
        }
   if playerOneCardValue > 0 {
        print("if statement performed")
        compareCardValuesForWinner()
        commitToNewPhase()
    }


}
```

Now, let me be clear, the issue isn't the functions I'm using inside this function, its how to listen for the other players value. Currently right now I have a while loop that keeps going until the value is changed, however this eventually causes the app to crash is it's generating so much junk.

How can I do this in a better and more efficient way that will allow me to 'listen' and wait for the other players input, and for the app to receive it? In other words, how can I wait for the other players data with out continuing with the app?

Comment: None of the code you shared interacts with Firebase, although I suspect `checkCardValue` may do that. Please share a [minimal, complete verifiable example that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'll clarify, some of the variables I'm using are references. I'll edit the code above.

Comment: But listening for value changes is the default behavior when interact with the Firebase Database. A single [call to `ref.observe(FIRDataEventType.value`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events) should do the trick if I understand your problem correctly (which an MCVE will show).

Comment: Oh, I see. I understand what you're saying. I was using a similar statement like that in another file. Sorry, wasn't thinking of that, it should do the trick!